# Selenium web scraping: How to find an element on a reactive website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am on a project that needs to get some information from a website and i wanted to automnatizate this process, but i am a begginer with the technology to achive this.

I found this library(Selenium) for python on the internet and i thougth it maight be a solution.

I succeded the firsts steps (Accepting cookies, locating the "Access" button and clicking on it). the problem comes when the "Access" button is clicked. It shows a little form to input the user and password, but i couldn't found them using the *driver.find_...* methods, so i began to look for the elements on the html document and it seems that this form is injected after clicking on the "Accept" button.

Is there any strategy to find the input elements for introducing the user and password after clicking the button?

[HTML code of the website without having clicked de "Access" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9kvv.png)

[HTML code after clicking on the "Access" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTI3J.png)

Thank you

The website link is: https://www.bbva.es/personas/experiencias/bbva-valora/analiza-vivienda.html

Comment: can you provide a link to that web page?

Comment: https://www.bbva.es/personas/experiencias/bbva-valora/analiza-vivienda.html It is a bank website that evaluates the price of a house. I have the user and password but when i try to find the input elements with id "user" and "password" to apply the sendKeys method, i cant find this input elements, but i can easily find them on the chrome inspector

Comment: Sorry the tag is name, not id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe class="iframe__base" title="People Login" id="tab-personas-iframe" width="100%" style="max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 384px;" src="/nimbus/login.html?conf=net/login&amp;http_contactid=04a341b5-c0ce-454a-8854-be6b12299c9a" scrolling="no">Your browser does not support iframes</iframe>
```

Your elements are inside an iframe.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
driver.get('https://www.bbva.es/personas/experiencias/bbva-valora/analiza-vivienda.html')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".cookiesgdpr__acceptbtn.btn__basic.btn__medium-blue"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".header__actions__item__link.header__actions--menu.header__access"))).click()
```

So here you have to switch to the iframe and then find element

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tab-personas-iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@data-testid='login-form-user']"))).send_keys("USER")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@data-testid='login-form-password']"))).send_keys("PASSWORD")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@data-testid='login-form-submit']"))).click()
```

To get where you want after you click the accept popup and the acceso item you just switch frames and send key.